# how to create a single annotation accept multiple values in Java

Tags: java, annotations, jira, sonarqube

I have a Annotation called

```
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.SOURCE )
@Target( ElementType.METHOD )
public @interface JIRA
{
    /**
     * The 'Key' (Bug number / JIRA reference) attribute of the JIRA issue.
     */
    String key();
}
```

which allows to add annotation like this

```
@JIRA( key = "JIRA1" )
```

is there any way to allow this to happen

```
@JIRA( key = "JIRA1", "JIRA2", .....  )
```

the reason is, we currently annotate the test
against a Jira task or  bug fix, but sometimes, 
then the value will get parsed by sonar.
problem is a single test covers more then 1 bug.

Comment: Nice use of annotations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your  `key()` function to return `String[]` rather than `String` then you can pass various values using `String[]`

```
public @interface JIRA {
/**
 * The 'Key' (Bug number / JIRA reference) attribute of the JIRA issue.
 */
String[] key();
}
```

Use it like below

```
@JIRA(key = {"JIRA1", "JIRA2"})
```